# useradd --no-log-init [comprehension question]

Tags: linux, debian, logs, options, useradd

**TLDR**: How is `useradd --no-log-init` actually used [in GNU/Linux [Debian]?

I read the command's `man` and `info` page about this option as: »*user will not be listed in the `lastlog` and `faillog` files ⁄ output*«. I know that the `PAM` module took over most of the actual login work. I understand the `lastlog` and the `faillog` commands, and I'm aware that via the latter e.g. the number of login attempts and such can be set.

I also know that bad login attempts are recorded in `/var/log/utmp`. This strengthens my *suspicion* that this command is »leftover« from back then before `PAM` module took over the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [useradd.c source](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/coverage/shadow-4.1.5.1/src/useradd.c.gcov.frameset.html) there is this bit that shows the following.

Assuming the command line switch `--no-log-init` was set, the `faillog_reset` and `lastlog_reset` functions are called:

```
if ((!lflg) && (getpwuid (user_id) == NULL)) {
                 faillog_reset (user_id);
                 lastlog_reset (user_id);
```

When `lastlog_reset` is called this bit will modify the `lastlog` file:

```
     fd = open (LASTLOG_FILE, O_RDWR);
     if (   (-1 == fd)
         || (lseek (fd, offset_uid, SEEK_SET) != offset_uid)
         || (write (fd, &ll, sizeof (ll)) != (ssize_t) sizeof (ll))
         || (fsync (fd) != 0)
         || (close (fd) != 0)) {
```

The above shows the file `lastlog` being opened for read & write (`O_RDWR`) followed by a `if` statement that makes sure the file was opened successfully followed by a seek within the file to a location and a `write` of the new user's info to the file. Afterwards the file is closed.

Based on this I would assume that that option controls whehter a user's UID is added to the `lastlog` "database" file and nothing more.